# doesn't sort correctly with ties

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use row_number to calculate median, lower quartile, and upper quartile for a box plot chart. However, my row_number sort is off because of ties.

Here is some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE EStats    
(
    PersonID            VARCHAR(30)     NOT NULL,
    Grade               VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL,
    CourseDate          Date            NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO EStats
(
    PersonID, Grade, CourseDate
)

VALUES
    ('100', '91', '2010-03-01'),
    ('101', '96', '2010-03-01'),
    ('102', '88', '2010-03-01'),
    ('103', '92', '2010-03-01'),
    ('104', '81', '2010-03-01'),
    ('105', '85', '2010-03-01'),
    ('106', '91', '2010-03-01'),
    ('107', '89', '2010-03-01'),
    ('108', '99', '2010-03-01'),
    ('109', '88', '2010-03-01'),
    ('110', '81', '2011-03-02'),
    ('111', '77', '2011-03-02'),
    ('112', '88', '2011-03-02'),
    ('113', '76', '2011-03-02'),
    ('114', '69', '2011-03-02'),
    ('115', '70', '2011-03-02'),
    ('116', '75', '2011-03-02'),
    ('117', '88', '2011-03-02'),
    ('118', '76', '2011-03-02'),
    ('119', '95', '2012-03-01'),
    ('120', '96', '2012-03-01'),
    ('121', '90', '2012-03-01'),
    ('122', '80', '2012-03-01'),
    ('123', '85', '2012-03-01'),
    ('124', '94', '2012-03-01'),
    ('125', '89', '2012-03-01'),
    ('126', '97', '2012-03-01'),
    ('127', '94', '2012-03-01'),
    ('128', '72', '2012-03-01'),
    ('129', '88', '2012-03-01'),
    ('130', '91', '2012-03-01')
```

Here is one of my inner queries that shows the sort not working:

```
SELECT
    CourseDate,
    Grade,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY LEFT(CourseDate, 4)
        ORDER BY Grade ASC) AS RowAsc,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY LEFT(CourseDate, 4)
        ORDER BY Grade DESC) AS RowDesc
FROM EStats
```

Notice that for CourseDate 2010-03-01 the RowAsc does this:

```
10
9
8
6
7
5
3
4
2
1
```

However, I need all of the rows to have a number in sequential order so that I can calculate median in the case where an even amount of numbers exists. (Rank and dense_rank don't work because of the "gaps" they leave).

Actually, below is the entire thing. Again, I'm trying to calculate median, lower quartile, upper quartile, min, and max for a blox plot chart. ANY help is really appreciated!

```
WITH Q3 AS
(
    SELECT
        CourseDate,
        AVG(CAST(Grade AS Numeric)) AS Median

    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            CourseDate,
            Grade,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY LEFT(CourseDate, 4)
                ORDER BY Grade ASC) AS RowAsc,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY LEFT(CourseDate, 4)
                ORDER BY Grade DESC) AS RowDesc
        FROM EStats
    )x
    WHERE 
        RowAsc IN (RowDesc, RowDesc - 1, RowDesc + 1)
    GROUP BY CourseDate
    --ORDER BY CourseDate
),

Q2 AS
(
    SELECT
        x.CourseDate,
        AVG(CAST(Grade AS Numeric)) AS LowerQuartile

    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Estats.CourseDate,
            Estats.Grade,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY LEFT(EStats.CourseDate, 4)
                ORDER BY Grade ASC) AS RowAsc,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY LEFT(Estats.CourseDate, 4)
                ORDER BY Grade DESC) AS RowDesc
        FROM EStats JOIN Q3 on EStats.CourseDate = Q3.CourseDate
        WHERE EStats.Grade < Q3.Median 
    )x
    WHERE
        RowAsc IN (RowDesc, RowDesc - 1, RowDesc + 1)
    GROUP BY x.CourseDate
),

Q4 AS
(
    SELECT
        x.CourseDate,
        AVG(CAST(Grade AS Numeric)) AS UpperQuartile

    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Estats.CourseDate,
            Estats.Grade,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY LEFT(EStats.CourseDate, 4)
                ORDER BY Grade ASC) AS RowAsc,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY LEFT(Estats.CourseDate, 4)
                ORDER BY Grade DESC) AS RowDesc
        FROM EStats JOIN Q3 on EStats.CourseDate = Q3.CourseDate
        WHERE EStats.Grade > Q3.Median 
    )x
    WHERE
        RowAsc IN (RowDesc, RowDesc - 1, RowDesc + 1)
    GROUP BY x.CourseDate
)

SELECT Q3.CourseDate, Q3.Median AS Median, Q2.LowerQuartile, Q4.UpperQuartile, MIN(EStats.Grade) AS Min, MAX(EStats.Grade) AS Max
FROM Q3
    JOIN Q2 ON Q3.CourseDate = Q2.CourseDate
    JOIN Q4 ON Q3.CourseDate = Q4.CourseDate
    JOIN EStats ON Q3.CourseDate = EStats.CourseDate
GROUP BY Q3.CourseDate, Q3.Median, Q2.LowerQuartile, Q4.UpperQuartile
ORDER BY Q3.CourseDate
```

Comment: You probably want to use `rank()` instead.

Comment: Can you post what you want as the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the median:

```
select avg(case when seqnum*2 = totnum+1 then col
                when seqnum*2 in (totnum, totnum + 2) then col
            end)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by col) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as totnum
      from t
     ) t
```

It looks arcane, but the idea is to do the average that you want for the even numbers and the single value for the others.  If using SQL Server, recall that it uses integer division.  You can actually simplify the above to:

```
select avg(case when seqnum*2 in (totnum, totnum+1, totnum+2) then col end)
```

This works because an odd total cnt just matches `totnum+1` and the even matches the other two values.